# Are statements in printf() executed from right to left?

Tags: c, logic, compiler-optimization

If C Compiler works from left to right then why is the following code's output in a way as if it is executing from right to left?

```
int x = 15 ; 
printf("%d %d %d", x!=15, x=20, x<30);
```

Output : 
    1 20 1

Comment: No, the order is unspecified. What you're doing is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Just to clear up any potential confusion - they may be executed in a certain order on your system, but they may execute in any other order on another computer or with another compiler.

Comment: "If C Compiler works from left to right then why...?"  This is like saying "If money is free then why when I went to the bank and asked for some they didn't give me any?" :-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, those are *expressions* and not statements.

Secondly, the order of argument evaluation is *unspecified*. You can't tell in what order the arguments will be evaluated, and your code would lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

For more information about evaluation order and *sequencing* see e.g. [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order).