# How does printf() execute its arguments with prefix and postfix unary operators?

Tags: printf, prefix, unary-operator, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

I wrote a simple code for printf in C with unary prefix operator as the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i=5;
    printf("%d %d %d",++i,i,i+1);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
6 6 6
```

Now, what I have understood is that C compilers usually execute printf() arguments from right to left and so in that case i+1 should be 6 (since i is 5), i should be 5 and ++i would first become 6 and then print. Hence expected output in my opinion should be:
`6 5 6`

If it executes from left to right, we should get `6 6 7`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are statements in printf() executed from right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053981/are-statements-in-printf-executed-from-right-to-left)

Comment: So basically there is no way to predict how the compiler will execute the arguments? I get the same result when doing `printf("%d %d %d",++i,i,i);` instead of `printf("%d %d %d",++i,i,i+1);`. So even when I am giving 3  arguments of integer data type on the same compiler, the execution order is different.

Comment: *"So basically there is no way to predict how the compiler will execute the arguments?"* Correct, it's undefined behaviour, i.e. the language spec does not require the compiler to evaluate in any particular order.

Comment: Got it, thank you.